# pandas: all NaNs when subtracting two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two series. I want to subtract one dataframe from another dataframe, even though they have a different number of columns.

```
>df1

index   0   1   2    3    4    5
TOTAL   5  46  56  110  185  629

>df2 
index   1   2   3    4    5
Use     25  37  86  151  512
```

I would assume that subtracting two dataframes with different dimensions would *only* result in NaNs in the mismatched columns (in this case, Column 0). The remaining columns would be the result of df1[1]-df2[1], df1[2]-df2[2], etc.

```
>df1 - df2
index   0    1   2   3   4   5
TOTAL   NaN  21  19  24  34  117
```

But this is not the case. This is what happens when I subtract the dataframes?

```
>df1 - df2
index   0   1   2   3   4   5
Use     NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
TOTAL   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I also tried just subtracting the values:

```
>df1.values - df2.values
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-376-1dc5b3b4ad3e>", line 1, in <module>
    total_drugs.values-(restraints_drugs.values+norestraints_drugs.values)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,6) (1,5)
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using pandas 0.18.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are subtracting two dataframes.  ***Both*** column and row indices must match.  In your case, the row indices `TOTAL` and `Use` do not match.

To get what you're looking for, you want to subtract the series `df2.ix['Use']` from `df1`

```
df1.sub(df2.squeeze())
```

[image]

Or:

```
df1.sub(df2.ix['Use'])
```

Or:

```
df1.sub(df2.loc['Use'])
```

Or:

```
df1 - df2.ix['Use']
```

Or:

```
df1 - df2.loc['Use']
```

Comment: Thanks! The squeeze() solution worked perfectly. I knew the column indices had to match but didn't realize the row indices had to match as well.

Answer (score 3):

Since both dataframes need to have the same index, so you can reset the index and then perform the subtraction on dataframes.

Use this and then perform subtraction:

```
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Once the index has been reset to default values then you can perform the subtraction/addition or anything.

```
df1-df2
```